# discord py bot send message more than one time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my code :

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def spambot(ctx):
    await ctx.author.send("message")
    await ctx.send("check your dms")
```

This sends the message and afterwards one notification. How can I repeat this process several times?

Comment: And what exactly do you want to do (maybe also with that code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're asking how to put this in a loop.

```
import asyncio

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def spambot(ctx):
    for i in range(10): #you can change 10 to any number, this loops the command 10 times
        await ctx.author.send("message")
        await ctx.send("check your dms")
        await asyncio.sleep(1) #this adds a delay so your bot doesn't get rate limited
```